# C# Create Object.ToInt() Like Object.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net

i need help to create method for easy  convert string to int like Object.ToString() Method .

```
    public int Object.ToInt(){
        ?????????
    }
```

please help me for create this method .

i can use it ?

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int ToInt32(this object Str)
    {
        if (Str != null && Str.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            try
            { 
                return Convert.ToInt32(Str);
            }
            catch { return default(int); } 
        }
        return default(int); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: You need to read more about [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: What would be the result of your method when passing the string `"Hello world"`? If you yourself can't answer that question, then there's no way a computer can.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis I want to use the method may eventually be converted or not. Convertible depends on me being where I call this method. Is is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method already exists - [`Object.GetHashCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx).

It may not do quite what you want to do though - but keep in mind that it's realistically impossible to do what you want, and this method does indeed produce an integer for every object.

You may also want to look at [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys(v=vs.110).aspx). It will do more of what you expect, but it won't work for every object - for most cases you will get an `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class EX
{
    public static int ToInt32(this object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            return default(int);
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fails if the parameter is no number or even a long. Maybe some exception-handling omitted for simplicity?

Comment: Agree. But that would count for every solution, right?

Comment: Not for `ToString` where you can use **any** object (however the result may be odd).

Comment: Maybe use the hashcode then?

Comment: That isn't the equivalent of parsing something to an int @DavidPilkington

Comment: You could argue that he is not asking you to parse it all, but rather for an integer representation of the object which is different

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a really bad idea. When creating those so-called [extension-methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977.aspx) you should ask yourself if **every** instance of an `object` could be converted to an int, which I doubt is what you expect. What would you expect when a user writes this:

```
ToInt("anyString");
```

However you can think of a string-representation of any arbitrary object. So you´d better define a helper-class for that that converts your number or simply call [`int.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.